# command line remove 'n' lines from file

Tags: command-line, bash

So I want to tail a file and remove the number of lines from the file is that possible with one line line in Linux? Almost essentially just moving lines of text from one file to another.

**For example:**

```
tail -8 foo-file.txt >> newfile.txt;
```

now... remove -8 lines from `newfile.txt`.

Comment: Do you want the last 8 lines, or everything *but* the last 8 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is close, you just need to change the way you are asking for the lines. Below I changed your "-8" to "-n 8" to ask for 8 lines.

```
tail -n 8 foo-file.txt >> newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Wow i thought the -n was for a numeric offset.  I'll give it try!